How can I declare a string NumPy array?
Below is my code:
import numpy as np

row_length = 5
col_length = 3
x = np.empty([row_length,col_length],dtype=str) 
x[1,2]='ddd'
print(x)

and the result is:
[['' '' '']
 ['' '' 'd']
 ['' '' '']
 ['' '' '']
 ['' '' '']]

why? The result I expected is:
[['' '' '']
 ['' '' 'ddd']
 ['' '' '']
 ['' '' '']
 ['' '' '']]

Who can tell me how to fix it?

Your issue is that dtype=str defaults to strings of length 1. Fix it by specifying the max length:
import numpy as np
row_length = 5
col_length = 3

# Specify the maximum string length (e.g., 10 characters)
x = np.empty([row_length, col_length], dtype='<U10') 
x[1, 2] = 'ddd'
print(x)

